# Where to place Spring @Async in a stack of methods calls

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, asynchronous

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.x, and in details, I am using the `@Async` annotation. My problem is that I have the following method in a repository.

```
@Repository
class Repository {
    @Async
    CompletableFuture<String> findSomething() {
        /* Some code that returns something */
    }
}
```

And then, I have the following method in a service, which calls the above repository.

```
@Service
class Service {
    private Repository repository;
    // ...
    @Async
    CompletableFuture<String> findSomething() {
        return repository.findSomething()
    }
}
```

My question is: should I place the `@Async` annotation **also** in the `service.findSomething()` method? Or should I place the annotation **only** in the service method?

I mean, Spring should schedule the execution of a method marked with `@Async` annotation in a dedicated thread. Is it correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, it’s the driver that I am using to connect to the database that uses an asynchronous model. So it is not my choice to use @Async, but rather a need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotating a method with `@Async` will cause the caller to return immediately and the actual execution will occur in a separate thread as part of a task submitted to the default `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` (if you haven't configured another one). Please see the relevant spring [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-async).

That being said, for your goal there's no added benefit in nesting the `@Async`. If your goal is to make `Repository.findSomething` asynchronous and to be able to call it from different places, not only `Service.findSomething`, you should annotate only this method.

Also, `Service.findSomething` is asynchronous itself, even if not annotated with `@Async`, in the scenario you depicted. The method is not blocking by calling `CompletableFuture.get()` and it will return immediately, although it will not be executed in a separate thread.